# Sharing text from clipboard

Tags: java, android

I ask all people of good will for a little help!

My code for copying text from textview is:

```
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(returnedText.getText());
```

My code for sharing copied text:

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "Should be copied text from Clipboard here";
            String shareSub = "My subject";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

I have a problem, what should I do in order to send automatically into the `shareBody` of copy the text from the clipboard ??? This means that instead of `Should be copied text from Clipboard here` the whole text is already saved in the body of the message in email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understand correctly. You want the text from the textview to be assigned to the `shareBody` variable?
In that case you can do

```
String shareBody = returnedText.getText().toString();
```